# How to create indexed view with select distinct statement in sql 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

My view named "Ge_Entry" is running very very slow so want to create indexed view with select distinct statement but sql server not allowing it.

So i want to know is there any way to create i.view with s.dist statement.

So that i can create indexes on this view for fast results.

Thanx

Neel

Comment: No, you cannot use `DISTINCT`. Is there some column or combination of columns that some condition could be applied against that would produce the rows that you're interested in?

Answer (score 23):

You can't use distinct. But you could use `COUNT_BIG(*)` and `GROUP BY`, possibly:

```
CREATE VIEW v1
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT ColumnA,ColumnB,COUNT_BIG(*) as Cnt
    FROM BaseTable
    GROUP BY ColumnA,ColumnB
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_v1 ON v1 (ColumnA,ColumnB)
GO
```

Instead of `DISTINCT ColumnA,ColumnB`

---

Most of the rules for creating indexed views appear to relate to the efficiency of maintaining the index. Imagine you have a base table with the following content:

```
ID        ColumnA        ColumnB
1         abc            def
2         abc            def
3         ghi            jkl
```

And you *were* allowed to create your view based *purely* on distinct. Now, you delete the row with `ID 2` from the table. Should SQL Server remove the row `abc,def` from the view's index? It can only find out by scanning the entire base table again.

Contrast this with my above view definition. Here's what the views data looks like:

```
ColumnA      ColumnB        Cnt
abc          def            2
abc          def            1
```

If you delete the row with `ID 2` from the base table, SQL Server can subtract 1 from the `Cnt` column for the row `abc,def`. If that column's new value is `0`, it knows it should delete that row from the index. Conversely, if the value is `>0`, then it knows that there are still rows in the base table for this value.

Comment: Damien, Lot of thanx for your broad reply and i understood that indexed view does not support select distinct statement, Actually View "Ge_Entry" contains lot of views. so i am asking to create indexed view

Comment: @Kamal - is my solution (instead of using `DISTINCT`, using `GROUP BY` on all columns) suitable for you, or is there an issue with it? (Not sure by your comment)